# Unsuccessful install HHVM on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, hhvm

I try to install HHVM on Mac. I use this official link https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/mac. I did `brew tap hhvm/hhvm`. After that I tried to do `brew install hhvm`. But I got next error:

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/user/Library/Logs/Homebrew/hhvm-4.118/01.cmake:
-- Could NOT find LibElf (missing: LIBELF_INCLUDE_DIRS)
-- Performing Test ELF_GETSHDRSTRNDX
-- Performing Test ELF_GETSHDRSTRNDX - Failed
CMake Error at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.21.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find LibDwarf (missing: LIBELF_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.21.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  CMake/FindLibDwarf.cmake:56 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake:259 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:112 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/hhvm-4.118-20210716-11584-nhka0x/hhvm-4.118.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/hhvm-4.118-20210716-11584-nhka0x/hhvm-4.118.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I tried to install libelf with the help of homebrew. But it doesn't help me :(. Could anyone help me. I wasted 2 days to solve this problem but couldn't. Would be really grateful any help.

Comment: HHVM web page has several community links (Facebook, Twitter, Slack), which you will probably have a much better chance of finding someone familiar with installing, building, and running HHVM on macOS.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: any update here @NN_05 ?